# delete results of a select with a JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table of `users` that may or may not have `photos` uploaded. I want to delete any users that *don't* have photos. Right now I can get the users with no photos like this:

```
SELECT a.id FROM users a
LEFT JOIN images b
ON a.id = b.user_id
WHERE b.user_id is null
```

However, I'm a little stumped on how to actually make the delete happen.

This doesn't work:

```
DELETE FROM users c WHERE c.id IN ( SELECT a.id FROM users a
    LEFT JOIN images b
    ON a.id = b.user_id
    WHERE b.user_id is null
    )
```

And neither does this:

```
DELETE FROM users a
LEFT JOIN images b
ON a.id = b.user_id
WHERE b.user_id is null
```

What's the right way to do a delete on the results of a JOIN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing your 2nd example failing because it is referencing the table in the subquery, but it shouldn't actually need to:

```
DELETE FROM users c WHERE c.id NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM images);
```

Otherwise, I would've done this:

```
DELETE FROM users 
USING users AS u LEFT JOIN images AS i ON u.id = i.user_id 
WHERE i.user_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE users
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM images i
    WHERE users.user_id = i.user_id)
```

Comment: I've never been a fan of correlated subqueries. Assuming that works, wouldn't it run the subselect separately for each row of users?

Comment: The query processor is smart enough to just do a join - it's query processing 101 so I think most database servers out there would figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there with the delete with joins query but need to give the table from which to delete.

Try this:

```
delete a.* from users a left join images b on a.user_id=b.user_id where b.user_id is null;
```